# Siddhi stream topic rejection

Tags: siddhi

While trying to specify a topic to use with the siddhi engine it gets rejected. Is there anything wrong with a topic such as:

> STREAM_162_18_73_15_80_VMC_3Axis_000_AxesLinear_X

Is there any documentation about siddhi's topic requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underscores aren't allowed. You'll find documentation [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB320/Managing+Topics+and+Sub+Topics).

Comment: I tried using a topic name like `STREAM.166.78.63.95.80.VMC.3Axis.000.AxesLinear.X` but got rejected. Do you have any advice for this topic creation?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are referring to MQTT topic for input stream, the ASCII format is supported for topic naming. Please visit this [link](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/966/should-i-use-special-characters-in-mqtt-topics?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for more info.